# (Arduino) How to isolate the color temperature value and print it to a specific color?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am new to arduino and I am just wondering how to isolate the color temperature value and assign it to a specific color.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_TCS34725.h"



 Adafruit_TCS34725 tcs = Adafruit_TCS34725(TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_700MS, TCS34725_GAIN_1X);


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);


  if (tcs.begin()) {
      Serial.println("Found sensor");

  }
}

void loop() {


  uint16_t r, g, b,c, colorTemp, lux ;

   tcs.getRawData (&r, &g, &b, &c);

   colorTemp = tcs.calculateColorTemperature_dn40 (r, g, b,c);


   if (4025<= (colorTemp, DEC) && (colorTemp, DEC) <= 4200) {
   Serial.print("Green") ;
}
     else
      {Serial.print(" ");}
}
```

when I try to run this code, it just keeps printing Green even though the color temperature doesn't match the constraints.

Comment: When you say that *"it doesn't match the constraints"*, what do you mean by that? what's the value of `colorTemp`? Also, what's `(colorTemp, DEC)` supposed to mean?

Comment: What i am basically trying to achieve is to have an RGB sensor pointed towards a colored sticky note and it would print to a certain color if it meets a certain range of color temparature. the value of colorTemp fluctuate from 4025K to 4200K. From what I understand is (colorTemp, DEC) to mean is that it would convert it into a decimal whole value

Comment: Have you ever measured a value outside this range?

Comment: I actually tried that after rereading your comment and try to understand what I am actually trying to achieve and it worked, so thank you